# Custom status bar notification

Tags: android, notifications

I got a custom status bar notification. There is a "Play" and "Next" image on it.
I want to send a Broadcast Intent to a Service when the "play" or "next" image is pressed.

```
notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, title + "\n"
        + text, System.currentTimeMillis());
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, actionOnClick, 0);
notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
        R.layout.custom_player_notification);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.custom_player_notification_title,
        title);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.custom_player_notification_text, text);
notification.contentView = contentView;
```

This is the code.
The ContentView offers the possibility to set "setOnClickPendingIntent" and "setOnClickFillInIntent". How can I use them to send this broadcast?
I want to send a broadcast because I dont want to launch an activity.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to send a Broadcast Intent to a Service when the "play" or "next" image is pressed

I would suggest that you want to send a command via `startService()` rather than a broadcast.

> How can I use them to send this broadcast?

You can try calling `setOnClickPendingIntent()`, supplying a `PendingIntent` you create via the static `getBroadcast()` method on `PendingIntent` (for a broadcast) or `getService()` (for a command to be sent via `startService()`).

Bear in mind that none of this will work on most Android devices available at present. I think buttons-in-`Notifications` works starting on Android 4.0, perhaps 3.0, but definitely not before then.

Comment: Sir, Can you please give some focus on this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169367/android-update-specific-notification-from-multiple-notifications-which-have-rem

i will provide more information, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could put something similar to this in your onClick() method of the notification, directing it to a broadcast receiver.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, receiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("SomeInfoMaybe", info);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

And then the code for handling the next stage could go in here:

public class receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
    System.out.println("SomeInfoMaybe = " + bundle.getString("info"));
            //etc...
    }
```

}

calling .notify(); on your notification should help link to the broadcast receiver